# How to create restful web services on ejb 3.0?

Tags: rest, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x, netbeans-8

How to create restful web service on ejb 3.0. Can anyone share any tutorial about it?

I am using Netbean IDE 8 and Jboss 6.2.

Comment: JBoss EAP or JBoss AS? If you are using `JBoss EAP 6.2` then you have JavaEE 6 available and thus you can use `JAX-RS` api.

Comment: @G.Demecki yes I am using JBoss EAP 6.2 please share me tutorial link for this task.

Comment: Nope, find it yourself. JBoss implementation of the JAX-RS is `RESTEasy`. So I guess that RESTEeasy documentation would suit your needs.